# Forward declaration obscuring ancestor template parameter from nested template

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, visual-c++

**EDIT**: the code has been trimmed down to contain only what is necessary to reproduce the error.  The error occurs at `const V * Resolve(const Resource<T> *);` and is `error C2923: 'Resource' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'`.

I'm using MSVC++ 2010 Express to compile the code displayed at the end of this post and I get these errors:

```
1>test.cpp(119): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>          test.cpp(121) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Resource<T>::Api<U>::ContainerDerived<V>' being compiled
1>          test.cpp(136) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Resource<T>::Api<U>' being compiled
1>          test.cpp(143) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Resource<T>' being compiled
1>test.cpp(119): error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '&'
1>test.cpp(120): error C2923: 'Resource' : 'T' is not a valid template type argument for parameter 'T'
```

(line 119 in the code is this: `std::auto_ptr<Dependent<V> > Construct(const T &);`)

It seems that the forward declaration `template <typename V> class ContainerDerived;` causes the definition of `ContainerDerived` to lose 'visibility' of the T parameter in the ancestor class `Resource<T>`.

Here is what I've tried:

- Switch the definition order of `Dependent<V>` and `ContainerDerived<V>` (so the latter appears first), and change the forward declaration to `template <typename V> class Dependent;`.  This fixes ContainerDerived but causes the same issue with Dependent.
- Add `typedef T FooBar;` prior to either definition and switch all instances of 'T' to 'FooBar' in either/both of Dependent/ContainerDerived.  This compiles, but the intended specialization when 'T' and 'V' are the same type does not occur.

Basically, it seems like adding a forward declaration of something is obscuring the T parameter from its definition.  Anyone have any idea why this occurs?

Here is the code:

```
#include <memory>

template <typename TypeContainer, typename TypeContained>
class Proxy
{
public:
    class Container {};

    Proxy(TypeContainer * = NULL);
    Proxy(Proxy &);
    ~Proxy();
};

struct Dummy {};

template <typename T>
class Resource : public T, public Proxy<Resource<T>, Dummy>::Container
{
public:

    template <typename U>
    class Api
    {
    public:

        template <typename V> class ContainerDerived;

        template <typename V>
        class Dependent : public Proxy<ContainerDerived<V>, Dependent<V> > {};

        template <typename V>
        class ContainerDerived
        {
        public:
            const V * Resolve(const Resource<T> *);
        };

    };
};
```

Comment: Any chance you can make a smaller repro?

Comment: I edited the OP.  Keep in mind it has been stripped of everything not necessary to generate the error.

Comment: Can't tell yet if this is a compiler bug, but curious: if you use the injected-class-name instead of the template-id, as in `const V * Resolve(const Resource*);`, does that work?

Comment: It works, but one of the methods I removed in the stripped-down version takes a 'T &' as a parameter: `std::auto_ptr<Dependent<V>> Construct(const T & refResource)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a bit of complexity in these relationships.  Of the main issues, you must use `typename` preceding dependant names.

```
template <typename V>
class ContainerDerived : public ContainerBase<ContainerDerived<V>, Dependent<V> >
{
public:
        typedef typename Api::Dependant<V> DV;
        typedef typename Resource::T TX;
    std::auto_ptr<DV> Construct(const TX &);
        typedef Resource<typename Resource::T> TR;
    const V * Resolve(const TR *);
};
```

Comment: I think declaring a typedef of T and using that typedef in `Dependent` and `ContainerDerived` has fixed the problem.  I can't be sure as I have [other compilation problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145283/boost-container-fails-to-compile-with-undefined-but-declared-class).  Regardless, I don't see why a typedef should be necessary; T should be visible to everything within the `Resource<T>` declaration.